# how to post data by ID desc

Tags: php, database, mysqli, output

```
$query="select * from messages where client_id='$client_id' ORDER BY `id` DESC";
```

the script above doesn't seems to work, i want to select all data equal to the useer input while posting it in descending order

```
  $result = $mysqli->query( $query );

                                        while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
                                        {
                                                $mes_agent_id = $row->poster_id;
                                                $id = $row->msg_id;
                                                $mes = $row->message;
                                                $mes = nl2br($mes);
                                                $cdate = $row->date_post;
                                                $msg ="{$mes} <br> . {$cdate}";

                                                $query_agnt ="select * from agent_info where id='$mes_agent_id'";
                                                $result_agnt = $mysqli->query( $query_agnt );
                                                $row_agnt = $result_agnt->fetch_object();
                                                        $mes_agent_first = $row_agnt->first;
                                                        $mes_agent_last = $row_agnt->last;
//wall ===================================================
?>
<li class="bar<?php echo $id; ?>">
<div id="news-avatar">
<img src="data/agentpic/<?php echo $mes_agent_first.$mes_agent_last; ?>.jpg" style="height:50px;float:left;margin-right:10px;"/>
</div>
<div align="left" class="post_box">
<br><label><strong><?php echo $mes_agent_first.' '.$mes_agent_last; ?></strong></label> <br> <br>
<?php echo $msg; ?> 

<br><br><a href="#" class="comment" id="4">comment</a><br>
</div>
<div id='expand_box'>
<div id='expand_url'></div>
</div>
<div id="fullbox" class="fullbox<?php echo $id; ?>">
<div id="commentload<?php echo $id; ?>" >
```

how can i post data from database in descending order, while picking where the data should be selected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change this statement :

`$query="select * from messages where client_id='" . $client_id  ."' ORDER BY`id`DESC";`

Answer (score 1):

You must use " ` " with start and end of the column_name and table_name or just use column_name and table_name but never use both together.

You use like this :

```
"select * from `messages` where `client_id`='$client_id' ORDER BY `id` desc";
```

or you can use

```
"select * from messages where client_id='$client_id' ORDER BY id desc";
```

and better use addslashes() function in php with the $client_id for preventing sql injection.

Like this:

```
$client_id = addslashes($client_id);
"select * from messages where client_id='$client_id' ORDER BY id desc"
```

I hope it will be done for you.